# What Data adapter command should be used to update the database table via gridview in c# Winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, windows

I have this code where I'm trying to update a database from the C# gridview change made in windows application....

The issue occurs in declaring the adapter select command in the update button click event...

I'm not sure which select command or the update command to use such that it updates the datagridview change in the database table....

Could anyone point me in the right direction to solve this issue  ?

```
public partial class KnowledgeBaseForm : Form
{
    private SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter();

    private void button_retrievekb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT * From Table1", con);

            DT = new DataTable();
            SDA.Fill(DT);

            bindingsource.DataSource = DT;
            dataGridView.DataSource = bindingsource;

            if (DT.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                dataGridView.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
                dataGridView.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Knowledge Base Rules Found");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }   
}

private void button_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to Update these values?", "Confirm Update", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        //binding the datasource with the changes made in the gridview
        bindingsource.DataSource = dataGridView.DataSource;
        SDA.SelectCommand = (//some necessary command or NULL update command which needs to update my database);

        scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(SDA);                 
        SDA.Update((DataTable) bindingsource.DataSource);
        MessageBox.Show("Updates successfully submitted to CoSD");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider updating the `DataSource` property of your Grid after any changes were made to the data source associated to it (like `bindingSource`).

Perhaps something like the following :

```
SDA.Update((DataTable) bindingsource.DataSource);
// After updating everything, rebind your grid
dataGridView.DataSource = bindingsource.DataSource;
```

Comment: thanks for the input... but when i tried calling the methiod datagridview.DataBind().... its throwing an error "'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'DataBind' ... " Is this method an inbuilt method or do I need to create one ?

Comment: Actually no that is correct. `DataBind()` is used within Web Forms as opposed to WinForms. The issue might be related to the `DataSource` not being set / updated for you Grid within the Update call.

Comment: bindingsource.DataSource = dataGridView.DataSource;...... statement gets the updated data from the gridview.... I checked it while debugging.... the problem is occuring in the "select commnad of the update button click"... What do you think on this one......

Comment: You probably need to actually set the `SelectCommand` to whatever you need to pull your new data (e.g. `SELECT * FROM YourTable`). This should update the datasource using the `Update` command and then you can update your Grid by pointing to the updated data source.

Comment: I already have my updated data in the DT(data table) which is binded to the gridview... how can I use that... the above code has that part ....